# Possible to make new bootable USB while using a trial Ubuntu USB?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, iso

My Ubuntu system isn't working - I don't get past the splash screen and have tried boot repair (several times), fixing broken packages, recovery mode and so on, to no avail. The filesystem seemd to have errors though I don't know what this means or how to fix it. My Windows XP partition is not booting either and goes to a black screen.

I hadn't installed anything new before all this happened.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04 on an old bootable USB but would like to upgrade it to a newer version so I have more functionality on the internet until I manage to fix my booting problem.

I found an ISO for 14.04 on my main partition but when I tried to open it onto my USB using Startup Disk Creator I got the message: An uncaught exception was raised {Errno 13] Permission denied:'base_installable'. (I was trying to do this while using my old trial 13.04 USB as that's my only way to access the internet at present.)

Downloading an ISO while using the trial Ubuntu USB isn't working (I'll try to get the error message to clarify this). Yes I do have an external hard drive system, but haven't been able to access things from it or to save onto it. I have very little technical computer knowledge.

My last boot info message from trying boot repair is:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/14366339

My system is: Nvidia G72M graphics card, Quadro NVS 110M/Geoforce Go 7300 video controller, Ubuntu 14.04, Xfce interface, 32-bit, Dell Latitude D620M, Intel Core 2 processor 1.83 GHz, 2GB RAM, dual boot with small Win XP partition.

Many thanks if anyone is able to help.

Comment: 13.04 reached end of life years ago and so you should no longer be using it.  If your question is how to download a more recent version when that is the only working system you have, you will need to be more specific than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Downloading works if you have some storage to download to, like an external HDD. To fix the file system errors, you can try running `sudo fsck -y /dev/sdXY`, where X and Y are the designators of the relevant Ubuntu partition. Do it from the 13.04 USB.

Comment: I don't know what worked but my system fixed itself several times later when I tried to boot. I saw something like fsck running and it must have fixed the broken file system. Should I delete my question? I've now made an updated Ubuntu trial USB with 14.04.1 (the 14.04.3 version on the ubuntu download page didn't make a functional USB). Thank you very much for your suggestions. I always get permission denied when trying to save or access things in folder while using the trial USB.